# IOS Swift - Syncing between two UIPageViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller

Two page controllers added to my main UIViewController. I've implemented all data source methods, and paging works fine.

**Q:** Is it possible to sync the swipe, so when I'm moving one pageController, the other one is moving along? To be more specific I would like to be able to stop at the middle of the swipe and see the other pageController behave the same (pausing at the middle of the swipe).

[image]

Comment: Why don't you put both views on one page if you need synced swiping?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, maybe I was not clear... They are on the same page.

Comment: No, I mean both views on one page controller.

Comment: Basically I tried to simplify the question. The view that needs to be synced is behind another transparent view, and I'm trying to use the second view controller as a hidden "helper view"

Comment: Look for wwdc videos about UIScrollViews. There is one each year and I remember that they were explaining exactly cases like this. The logon screen of iOS uses this technique (when you slide a notification) and they explain how they did it.